# make distutils in Python automatically find packages

Tags: python, distutils, setup.py

When describing a python package in `setup.py` in `distutils` in Python, is there a way to make it so automatically get every directory that has a `__init__.py` in it and include that as a subpackage?

ie if the structure is:

```
mypackage/__init__.py
mypackage/a/__init__.py
mypackage/b/__init__.py
```

I want to avoid doing:

```
packages = ['mypackage', 'mypackage.a', 'mypackage.b']
```

and instead just do:

```
packages = ['mypackage']
```

and have it automatically find things like `a` and `b` since they have an init file. thanks.

Comment: Just make sure that you don't let any junk accumulate in your package structure before building if you do this.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

The easiest way (that I know of) is to use [`pkgutil.walk_packages`](http://docs.python.org/library/pkgutil.html#pkgutil.walk_packages) to yield the packages:

```
from distutils.core import setup
from pkgutil import walk_packages

import mypackage

def find_packages(path=__path__, prefix=""):
    yield prefix
    prefix = prefix + "."
    for _, name, ispkg in walk_packages(path, prefix):
        if ispkg:
            yield name

setup(
    # ... snip ...
    packages = list(find_packages(mypackage.__path__, mypackage.__name__)),
    # ... snip ...
)
```

Comment: There may (indeed, there most likely *are*) better ways to do this ... I just don't know them (yet) :-)

Comment: find_packages() from setuptools does exactly the same essentially, see my answer

Comment: @dm76 yes but the OP is asking for distutils, not setuptools. Am I missing something?

Comment: `__path__` return me `NameError`, I use `'.'` instead.

Comment: Downvoter - can you explain so I can make the answer better?

Comment: I just think @dm76 answer is better, although is not disutils

Answer (score 113):

I would recommend using the find_packages() function available with [setuptools](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/setuptools) such as:

```
from setuptools import setup, find_packages
```

and then do

```
packages=find_packages()
```

Comment: Note that `find_packages()` doesn't find > 3.3-style no-__init__.py packages. The ticket about this issue is at https://bitbucket.org/pypa/setuptools/issue/97. So for now, it's necessary to add `__init__.py` files in packages for `find_packages()` auto collection, or you must name them explicitly in `packages`.

Comment: Update: Even the explicit list causes problems if `__init__.py` files are not used on Python 3.3 (`package init file 'mymod/mysubmod/__init__.py' not found (or not a regular file)`).

Comment: Now there are also `find_namespace_packages()` (see https://setuptools.readthedocs.io/en/latest/setuptools.html#find-namespace-packages) which works with PEP 420 namespace packages (https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0420/)

Answer (score 19):

Same as dm76 answer, just that I also have tests in my repo, so I use:

```
from setuptools import find_packages

packages=find_packages(exclude=["*.tests", "*.tests.*", "tests.*", "tests"]),
```

Answer (score 2):

```
import re, os
def find_packages(path='.'):
    ret = []
    for root, dirs, files in os.walk(path):
        if '__init__.py' in files:
            ret.append(re.sub('^[^A-z0-9_]+', '', root.replace('/', '.')))
    return ret

setup(
...
packages = find_packages()
...
)
```