# Can't find submodule within package

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-import, modulenotfounderror

I feel a bit dumb asking this since there are a lot of similar questions, but I've honestly searched around a lot and could not find a solution for this. Here goes:

I have a Python package (on [TestPyPi](https://test.pypi.org/project/rens-paillier/), [here](https://gitlab.com/RensOliemans/paillier) is the source code, note that it uses and needs python3.8) with the following structure:

```
paillier/
    setup.py
    test/
    paillier/
        __init__.py
        keygen.py
        util/
            __init__.py
            math_shortcuts.py
```

My use case is: in `keygen.py`, I want to use `util/math_shortcuts.py`.
So, in `keygen.py`, I have the following import:
`from paillier.util.math_shortcuts import generate_coprime, lcm, get_mu`.
However, when I try to use my package (by doing `from paillier.keygen import generate_keys`), I am greeted with the Error `ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'paillier.util'`

This ModuleNotFoundError is always present when I install it using `pip` from `TestPyPi`, but it doesn't happen when I build the package locally: when I run `pip install -e .` in the `paillier/` directory (where `setup.py` lives), I *can* run `from paillier.keygen import generate_keys`, even when my working directory is somewhere else.

I've tried to do `from .util.math_shortcuts ...`, or `from util.math_shortcuts ...`, or `from paillier.paillier.util.math_shortcuts ...`, but all to no avail.

---

In short, when doing `pip install --index-url <TestPyPi> rens-paillier` my files can't seem to find the submodules.
However, when doing `pip install -e .` in the outer `paillier/` dir, it seems to work.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I ran into the same problem. (my -e installation worked, normal installation didn't) My solution is, to actually name the subpackages in the setup.py.

```
packages=['paillier', 'paillier.util']
```

While this works, I am not sure why :D

Comment: hi, this solved the first error I was getting, but I have submodules inside submodules. For example, I have a submodule inside the module 'paillier'. I can successfully install the package but I cannot find the modules within submodules. How can I refer them?

Comment: I'm not sure if you found the dependencies inside the submodules, but what I did was something like "from ..other_module.file import XXXX". That did the trick for me in the library.

Answer (score 1):

I found that removing the `packages` parameter from the `setup` function call in the setup.py file resolved a similar issue I had with my module not resolving submodules.

Answer (score 0):

looking around for the same question ([credits to this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12966216/make-distutils-in-python-automatically-find-packages)), the easiest is probably to use

```
setuptools.find_packages()
```

some optional arguments:

- `where="src"` for package structures where the files are in `src/`
- `exclude=["*-old"]` to exclude some packages (in my case, the `my_package-old` that I want to keep until my refactoring is done)